# Is there a way to replace the string referencing the project name used by the @addTagHelper with something stronger

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-tag-helpers

I am using the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.TagHelpers package in dotnet core and I want to remove the dependency on names or at least have it dynamic.

```
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers 
@addTagHelper *, MyWonderfulApp
```

Any ideas on how to replace the "MyWonderfulApp" part with something stronger?

Something along the lines of

```
@addTagHelper Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()
```

Comment: @JoeAudette MyWonderfulApp is my assembly name

Comment: right and that is what must be, there is nothing different or stronger that can be used

Comment: @JoeAudette very helpful -_-

Comment: I hope that isn't sarcasm, I was trying to tell you the answer to your question is no, sorry if you don't like the answer.

Comment: @JoeAudette lol no offence intended XD